# Word match in a sentence - optimization

Tags: regex, string, optimization, dictionary

ILovePolitics, this is basically a sentence and has 3 words.

I want to know the best technique to extract those 3 words. I can use a dictionary, and check if this string has any sub string (that matches any word) keep it in the list.

if "love" is matched as sub-string that would get added into my list since love is within this string.

BUT this is more lik brute force where I will have to check every word with this string, what would be the best approach to optimize this requirement?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Can we see any code you've written?  Also, what language are you working in?

Comment: @SFarron I have been doing sentiment analysis on tweets (hash tags). I don't have any issues with the code.. My question is more like towards optimization..I have pre-processed 2.4 million tweets and out of them 1.2 m contain hash tags. I have successfully extracted what I need.. I want to know the best possible approach now.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo do you consider a word what start with camelcase?

Comment: To search in text: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If want to capture words that are CamelCase, then you could use a regex like this:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU8bA4/2)**

[image]

Captures: `I` `Love` `Politics`

On the other hand, if you want to capture words that also starts in lowercase, you could do:

```
([A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oU8bA4/3)**

Captures: `I` `Love` `Politics` `match` `only` `Camel` `Case`

Comment: I thought that as well..The sentence won't be in camel case all the time.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo in that case you can use the second regex